# Requisição Curl usando nodeJs retorna um body vazio

Tags: node.js, libcurl

Usei o Curl do site dos correios, para transformar em uma requisição nodejs(usei esse site para converter o curl em código js-> https://curl.trillworks.com/)

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Origin': 'https://www2.correios.com.br',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Referer': 'https://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/default.cfm',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8',
    'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.3.1385639005.1586277520; CFID=31280658; CFTOKEN=1c6b8efc2c6ad4c1-ED1DB9DE-FA31-5E5A-CF1D02F2BF2CB440; CFGLOBALS=urltoken%3DCFID%23%3D78315721%26CFTOKEN%23%3De66c3a82c674de4%2D861C7DF3%2DDAB6%2DE583%2DD427EAE724F26F87%26jsessionid%23%3D6CE45E28E642304EA69CD721D3293F2D%2Ecfusion01%23lastvisit%3D%7Bts%20%272020%2D04%2D23%2009%3A29%3A29%27%7D%23hitcount%3D5%23timecreated%3D%7Bts%20%272020%2D04%2D15%2010%3A52%3A13%27%7D%23cftoken%3D1c6b8efc2c6ad4c1%2DED1DB9DE%2DFA31%2D5E5A%2DCF1D02F2BF2CB440%23cfid%3D31280658%23; ssvbr0331_www2sro=sac2844SRO; _gid=GA1.3.940270031.1587816025; ssvbr0331_www2=sac2845; JSESSIONID=B7982AF26D30D28AD6F20CF6E39671C5.cfusion02; ssvbr0327_www2sro=sac2842SRO; sitecorreioscookie-%3FEXTERNO%3Fpool_site_institucional_443=AIBOKIMA; _gat_gtag_UA_564464_1=1; ssvbr0327_www2=sac2848'
};

var dataString = 'acao=track&objetos=JU763467155BR&btnPesq=Buscar';

var options = {
    url: 'https://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/ctrl/ctrlRastreamento.cfm?',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 302) {
        console.log(body);
        console.log(response);
    }else{
        console.log("a casa caiu");
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

quando rodo o script, ele retorna um body vazio, como na imagem abaixo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjqHl.png

ele retorna o código correto(302)... mas na hora de retornar o conteúdeo, não vem nada, sendo que eu testei o mesmo request no postman, e retornou um body com texto html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código `302` representa um redirecionamento, o novo URL deve estar presente no `Location` no cabeçalho de resposta.

---

Você tem duas soluções:

**1. Adicionar o `followAllRedirects: true`:**

```
request = request.defaults({
  followAllRedirects: true
});

request(options, callback);
```

O `followAllRedirects` é mencionado no [GitHub](https://github.com/request/request), como:

> followAllRedirects - follow non-GET HTTP 3xx responses as redirects (default: false)

Isso irá permitir seguir redirecionamento em método POST.

*Se deseja também manter o método POST para a página que foi redirecionada, utilize também `followOriginalHttpMethod: true`. Mas, acho que isso não será necessário.*

**2. Fazer uma nova requisição lendo o `Location`:**

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 302) {

        //Aqui faz outra requisição baseada no novo link que recebeu:
        request({url: response.headers['location'], method: 'GET',headers: headers}, novo_callback);


    }else{
        console.log("a casa caiu");
    }
}
```

Os headers de resposta podem ser acessados dentro do `callback`, usando o array `response.headers`, aparentemente. Então pode ler o "Location" e então utiliza-lo para obter o novo URL e fazer uma requisição diretamente para tal URL.

Comment: Minha experiencia com NodeJS é zero, então pode ter algum erro.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a resposta acima esteja correta, porém, você deve trocar o status code do seu if, e colocar 200, que é o códico de sucesso, para caso esteja tudo "ok", coloque:

```
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
    console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: Boa observação, funcionou, coloquei status 200 e pegou

Comment: Se resolveu o seu problema, marque a resposta como resolvida, não é obrigatório, mas ajuda na experiência do site e novos usuários que irão vir e tiver a mesma dúvida que a sua.